# Multiple comparisons from means and standard deviations

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

I am attempting to do a statistical comparison of the mean concentrations of certain ingredients between different varieties of a product, based on summary data.

An example table depicting the type of data I have is shown below, and I have the sample size.

[image: example table]

**My question:** What statistical test is appropriate to tell me if each of the pairwise differences between varieties is significant? I have seen some results pointing towards Tukey HSD but I don't understand well enough to feel confident that this is correct in the case of summary data vs. individual replicates.

I am mainly concerned with getting from point A (individual study summary data) to point B (pairwise significance results for each ingredient and pair of product varieties), but any statistics theory that can be explained along the way is excellent as I am curious to understand what's going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV! Please limit your post to a specific (preferably single) question. You can ask as many times as you want, but also have a look first whether some of your questions have already been answered elsewhere on the site. As an aside, your data cannot validate assumptions. At best you can check for (absence of) violations, but this is not evidence that your assumptions were correct.

Comment: Thanks Frans! I'll update the post to narrow down to a specific question and take a look at other answers to relevant questions.

Comment: If you have the sample size of each study, you could estimate pooled standard errors and go from there. Even better would be if you have the original data. In that case you could just do a factorial ANOVA for the product/ingredient combinations.

Comment: I do have sample size information, but I don't have the original data unfortunately. Getting pooled means and pooled standard errors from the individual study data appears straightforward, and the result would be a single table like the one in the original post (if I understand what you're suggesting). From here I am not sure how to proceed - what statistical test can be applied on this mean & standard error summary information to determine if the are are significant differences in any ingredient between any two varieties? Thanks!

Comment: Under the assumption of approximate normality you can use pairwise $t$-tests: $\frac{\bar{y}_1 - \bar{y}_2}{\text{SE}_{\text{pooled}}}$. Then correct for multiple testing.

Comment: The validity of an estimator, or perhaps the better term is relevance, depends on the population characteristics in the sense that one cannot assume that a mean value and a standard deviation are valid estimators of that population without fear of contradiction unless one has evidence of how that population should be distributed, e.g., what pdf.

Comment: Thanks Carl, in my case I am comfortable assuming that the population follows a normal distribution.

Comment: From what I have read, ANOVA and post-hoc tests such as Tukey assume homogeneity of variances. Is there a way to test this from summary data?